# Ruby on Rails 3 + Apache2 + Phusion Passenger: Bundler::GemNotFound exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, bundler, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app on an Apache2 server by using Phusion Passenger. While everything works well locally, I am getting the infamous "Bundler::GemNotFound" error while deploying:

```
Could not find abstract-1.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

All my gems are installed in my local home folder. Thus the passenger configuration lines from my Apache2 configuration file are as follows:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/regis/.gem/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/regis/.gem/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

I understand you would need more information to analyse the issue at hand, but I have no idea on how to diagnose this further.

Comment: What does typing `gem which abstract` print out? Have you ran `bundle install` to install all the gems needed by the app?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try doing `bundle install --path vendor/cache`

Comment: Great, that did it! Does that mean that Passenger is looking for the gems in the vendor/cache folder by default? Is it possible to change this setting?

Comment: Pretty much. You can change this by deleting the cache (folder) in vendor. Do bundle install again and it will do it normally.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  I have search the entire interwebs for this simple solution to a confusing and frustrating little problem that made no sense. THANK YOU

Comment: The issue with me, is that my bunlder is failing, I blame the two ruby version installed without RVM or rbenv:

    $ bundle install --path vendor/cache
    /opt/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-    1.3.5/bin/bundle:7:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler     (LoadError)
            from /opt/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-    1.3.5/bin/bundle:7


Line 7 is:
    require 'bundler'