# Could not find rack-1.2.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, passenger, rack

System: Ubuntu, Rails 3.0.10, Apache, Passenger

Why does passenger give me this error message when:

bundle update: 'Using Rack (1.2.3)

and bunble show rack: /home/tonic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3

Any ideas, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using RVM? Is perhaps `PassengerRuby` set to use a different Ruby to the one on your command line?

Comment: LoadModule passenger_module /home/tonic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-3.0.8/ext/apache2/mod_$
   PassengerRoot /home/tonic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-3.0.8
   PassengerRuby /home/tonic/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that what worked for me is

```
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```

...which is the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920872/ruby-on-rails-3-apache2-phusion-passenger-bundlergemnotfound-exception).